# Which service I have to use from azure for real time streaming provided by azure?

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-databricks

I'm trying to do real-time analytics with Azure, and when I have gone through services, I have seen three services provided by Azure are HDInsight(Kafka), Azure stream Analytics, and Azure Events hub what are the services do I have to use.
I'm trying stream data on real-time either from SQL server or from twitter or some other and to store in on Azure Data warehouse or Data Lake.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the high level question, Event Hubs (including Event Hubs Kafka) and HDInsight can be used for data ingestion. The first one provides a serverless service while the second one provides a managed Kafka cluster.

Azure Stream Analytics focuses on data processing, transformation and analytics. You can use a SQL query to do this and take data from Event Hubs (or IoT Hubs) and move it to various sinks such as SQL, SQL Data Warehouse, Data Lake, etc.

To answer your particular question, you can look at [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-twitter-sentiment-analysis-trends) showing how to use Event Hubs and Stream Analytics to process Twitter data.

Also, you mentioned you want to take data *from* SQL Server? Is it streaming data? Azure Stream Analytics support data from SQL for reference data (slow moving data used to enrich a stream of data). Are you looking for something to do ETL and move data from SQL server to other places at regular pace? For this Azure Data Factory or SQL Server Integration Services could be a good choice.

Let me know if this answers your question, I'll be happy to give you more info.

Jean-Sébastien 
(Azure Stream Analytics)

Comment: Hello Jean-Sébastien, thanks for your reply. I've been reading up on, and getting myself acquainted with, both ASA and ADF. Could you help me understand some of the use cases where one might prefer one of these services over the other? I understand that ADF is really powerful and can do tons of stuff, but surely there are some use cases where one could use either of them (eg. copy data from event hub and store in a SQL db?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I think the main differences are really about 2 dimensions: latency and stateless vs. stateful: ASA's best use cases are the ones you need low latency (ms to seconds), and/or when you need to perform analytics/calculation based on multiple events (i.e. aggregates, analytics functions). ADF use-cases are more related to ETL, when you can efficiently move and transform data from sources to destinations, with transformations usually related to a single event.